# google sheets or excel find most popular value

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the following columns

```
name gender

Dann Boy
Anne Girl
Dann Boy
Susan Girl
Anne Girl
Gil  Boy
```

I have the find out the most popular name for a boy and the most popular one for a girl.

For the above I would expect Dann for a boy and Anne for a girl.

What formula can I use? Mode returns only numbers, and without a condition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have data in `A2:B10` you can use this "array formula" in excel for the most common boy's name

`=INDEX(A2:A10,MODE(IF(B2:B10="Boy",MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0))))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If there are multiple names tied for most common, then the formula will return just the **first** of those positionally

This works because the `MATCH` function assigns the same number to each name (the position of the first instance), the `IF` function "filters" those numbers, so that you only get numbers for the boys...and `MODE` then finds the most common number, which is clearly the position of the first instance of the most common name - `INDEX` then returns that name.

If there are no repeated boy's names then the formula returns #N/A error

Note: exactly the same formula worked for me in google sheets - I'm surprised I didn't need to use `Arrayformula` around that - perhaps that's a feature of the new version?

Comment: Barry, a quirk of Google Sheets (old and new versions) is that INDEX automatically enables array calculations (as per eg SUMPRODUCT and LOOKUP in Excel).

Answer (score 1):

@Barry: if there are blank cells in between data range and if blank cells count is more than boy's name count then the formula returns #N/A. Atleast this part we can handle with little changes in your formula: 
=INDEX(A2:A10,MODE(IF(B2:B10="Boy",IF(A2:A10<>"",MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0)))))